# Android - webview removing header and footer displaying only selected contents

Tags: android, webview

i need to convert a complete website into an android app. But I don't want the header, menu and footer in every page to be displayed.

Is there any way I can just take the content of the webpage alone and display in web view.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using joomla...i have a solution that worked for me....

Go to template settings, hide the logo, menu and footer section

In your app you wll not see any header, footer and logo

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the website's source? If yes, it is much easier to write a css-file for mobiles (and use JS to detect the UserAgent) than to do any of that work in the mobile app itself.

However, if you really want to mess with the page on your device, you can extract the html-source, change it (delete the header+menu+footer), and load that changed source into the webview.